# Oracle 12c - Build select statements using values from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a complex need but i'll try to keep it simple and use my brain on an answer that fullfills my basic need.

I have a table, TABLE1, with 2 columns, `ID(INTEGER)`, `LVL_CNT(INTEGER)` & `CLOB_COLUMN(CLOB)`. `CLOB_COLUMN` will have a select statement. Following are the values held in each column to show an example.

ID = 1
LVL_CNT = 10
CLOB_COLUMN will have script as follows:

```
SELECT     'ID',
           'Name',
           'Description',
           'Group',
           'Level Count',
           'Usage',
           'Snapshot Date',
           'Conformed Hierarchy',
           'Level Name:',
           'Level Name:',
           'Level Name:',
           'Level Name:',
           'Level Name:',
           'Level Name:',
           'Level Name:',
           'Level Name:',
           'Level Name:',
           'Level Name:
FROM dual;
```

Currently, I am writing the CLOB script manually but I would like to build it automatically to avoid writing it for all records. 
"'Level Name:'" is iterated 10 times because LVL_CNT = 10. If LVL_CNT = 5 then iterate "'Level Name:'" 5 times. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want your query to return a variable number of columns, then you can only do that with dynamic SQL.  A regular SQL select statement has a fixed number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select rpad('level name:', lvl_cnt*length('level name:'), 'level name:') 
from yourtable
```

Should give you 'level name:level name:level name:level name:' for lvl_cnt=4

---

follow up for the task with (level name1: level name2:...)

There is a simple but not scalable solution. If you know your maximum lv_cnt and it is not very big [ max varcahr2 2000 / length('level name001') = 142] (example up to lvl_cnt = 4):

```
 select susbtr(
 rpad(
 rpad(
 rpad('level name1:', 
 2*length('level name1:'), 'level name2:'),
 3*length('level name1:'), 'level name3:'),
 4*length('level name1:'), 'level name4:'),
 1, lvl_cnt*length('level name1:')
 from dual
```

The will be complicated logic when you go over 10, 100,.. because it will affect overall length, but you can change format to 'level name001:' and keep it simple :).

...but if you think about it, it is like prebuild string

```
select substr('level name1:level name2:level name3:level name4:', 1, lvl_cnt*12) 
from dual
```

Comment: How can I use this method to add a number for every iteration? I.e. Level Name1:, Level Name2:, Level Name 3 for lvl_cnt=3.

Comment: you can't. You would need a different approach. Here are tasks that you need to solve: 1. generate list of numbers (dump version: 'select rownum from all_objects where rownum < lvl_cnt'); 2. learn about LISTARG function;

Comment: I will add a case with rpad to the answer, but it is not scalable